# why isn't the tscv function allowing for step-size other than 1?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

the [tsCV](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/blob/master/R/tscv.R) function from the `forecast` package allows for forecasting using a rolling forecast window. Why is it that the step-size is always 1 sample ahead, and the function doesn't allow for stepping k samples for each forecast?

My business scenario is that I have to predict 24 samples ahead (h=24), but I'm forecasting only at midnight of each day (k=24), it's **not** that I have to predict 24 hours ahead **every** hour. I would like to simulate that using `tsCV`.

Note that in the `sklearn` counterpart [TimeSeriesSplit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html) this functionality is implemented, and the difference between successive training sets isn't hard-coded to 1 sample.

Answer (score 1):

If your method is in the forecast class and you have more than 24 observations, you should have no problem in running **tsCV** with h = 24. It will return a matrix with h = 24 columns and the number of rows equals to your data size.

If you only want the cv errors for K=24, then you can do the following: if **d** is the number of days in your data you, the code

```
tsCV(data, forecast_method, h = 24)[24*(1:(d-1)),]
```

should return a error matrix for the whole day predicting only midnight (K=24). The code below illustrates this (d=5)

```
set.seed(10)
X <- ts(rnorm(5*24))
tsCV(X, rwf, h = 24)[24*(1:4),]
```

It returns a $4\times 24$ matrix, each row contains the prediction at midnight for some hour of that day, which is given by the column. For instance, element [2,15] is the prediction error at midnight of the second day for hour 15. Then you can apply a metric you see fit to choose the forecast method.

Edit: As you have stated, this is a hack, and quite a slow one actually since it runs 24X more than you actually need. I went to the source code of tsCV and changed it to add a "step" parameter.

The code for the function definition goes below, just copy and run this in a R script. I commented on the lines that I added or modified.

```
tsCV_step <- function (y, forecastfunction, h = 1, window = NULL, xreg = NULL, 
          initial = 0, step = 1, ...) 
{
  y <- as.ts(y)
  n <- length(y)
  step <- round(step)
  step_ind <- seq(step, n - 1L, by = step) ### Added line

  e <- ts(matrix(NA_real_, nrow = floor(n/step), ncol = h)) ### Modified line: n was replaced by floor(n/step)
  if (initial >= n) 
    stop("initial period too long")
  tsp(e)[-2] <- tsp(y)[-2] ### Modified line: [-2] added
  if (!is.null(xreg)) {
    xreg <- ts(as.matrix(xreg))
    if (NROW(xreg) != length(y)) 
      stop("xreg must be of the same size as y")
    tsp(xreg) <- tsp(y)
  }
  if (is.null(window)) 
    indx <- seq(1 + initial, n - 1L)
  else indx <- seq(window + initial, n - 1L, by = 1L)
  indx <- intersect(indx, step_ind) ### Added line
  for (i in indx) {
    y_subset <- subset(y, start = ifelse(is.null(window), 
                                         1L, ifelse(i - window >= 0L, i - window + 1L, stop("small window"))), 
                       end = i)
    if (is.null(xreg)) {
      fc <- try(suppressWarnings(forecastfunction(y_subset, 
                                                  h = h, ...)), silent = TRUE)
    }
    else {
      xreg_subset <- as.matrix(subset(xreg, start = ifelse(is.null(window), 
                                                           1L, ifelse(i - window >= 0L, i - window + 1L, 
                                                                      stop("small window")))))
      fc <- try(suppressWarnings(forecastfunction(y_subset, 
                                                  h = h, xreg = xreg_subset, ...)), silent = TRUE)
    }
    if (!is.element("try-error", class(fc))) {
      e[i/step, ] <- y[i + (1:h)] - fc$mean ### Modified Line: i replaced by i/step 
                                            ### for "e" first index
    }
  }
  if (h == 1) {
    return(e[, 1L])
  }
  else {
    colnames(e) <- paste("h=", 1:h, sep = "")
    return(e)
  }
}
```

The following example illustrates that it gives the same result as before and is way faster: tsCV_step took approximately 0.4 seconds to compute, while tsCV took more than 10 seconds. The all(step_err == no_step_err, na.rm = T) output shows that the hack output and tsCV_step output is the same, with the only difference that the hack goes to d now instead of (d-1), so the NA's will appear.

```
set.seed(10)
days = 100
data <- ts(rnorm(24*days))
K_step = 24

# Compute the errors with step and the time taken
init <- Sys.time()
step_err <- tsCV_step(data, rwf, h = 24, step = K_step)
tot_time_step <- Sys.time() - init


init <- Sys.time()
no_step_err <- tsCV(data, rwf, h = 24)[K_step*(1:d),]
tot_time_no_step <- Sys.time() - init

cat(paste("tsCV_step time taken: ", tot_time_step, "\n",
          "tsCV time taken: ", tot_time_no_step, sep = ""))


all(step_err == no_step_err, na.rm = T)
```

**Obs1:** I'm no expert on R programming, so I might have introduced a bug by changing the source code. It seems stable for your application if you are not using the other parameters like **window** and **xreg**.

**Obs2:** The NA's are also reported, just like in tsCV.

Comment: I did something similar: `ret <- ret[seq(attributes(ret)$dim[1]) %% 24 == 1,]` - but this is a hack, as the `tsCV` runs X24 times than necessary, right? (it's very slow when using a complicated forecast...)

Comment: Yes, I will try to think how to overcome that problem. I will edit my answer to clarify that!

Comment: wow thanks!!! checking if there's a simpler solution before accepting